# Int object not callable error in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an error when executing the following code.

```
class MinStack:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.stack = []
        self.top = -1
        self.min = 0
    def push(self, x: int) -> None:
        if self.top==-1:
            self.min = x
        elif x<self.min:
            self.min = x
        self.top = self.top + 1
        self.stack.append(x)
    def pop(self) -> None:
        self.top = self.top - 1
    def top(self) -> int:
        return self.stack[self.top]
def getMin(self) -> int:
        return self.min
```

I get the following error message

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Line 51 in __helper_select_method__ (Solution.py)
Line 69 in __helper__ (Solution.py)
Line 84 in _driver (Solution.py)
Line 93 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I found this explanation for the error:

```
In Python, a "callable" is usually a function. The message means you are treating a number (an >"int") as if it were a function (a "callable"), so Python doesn't know what to do, so it >stops.
```

I am unable to figure out where I have made the mistake.

Comment: I can't see any relation between the error message (which, by the way, is not how Python outputs such messages - how do you run your code?) and the code you posted, in which there isn't anything getting executed, just a class declaration.

Comment: obj = MinStack()
# obj.push(x)
# obj.pop()
# param_3 = obj.top()
# param_4 = obj.getMin()

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
class MinStack:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.stack = []
        self.top = -1
        self.min = 0
    def push(self, x: int) -> None:
        if self.top==-1:
            self.min = x
        elif x<self.min:
            self.min = x
        self.top = self.top + 1
        self.stack.append(x)
    def pop(self) -> None:
        self.top = self.top - 1
    def top(self) -> int:
        return self.stack[self.top]

    def getMin(self) -> int:
            return self.min

obj = MinStack()
obj.push(1)
obj.pop()
print(obj.top)
#-1
print(obj.getMin())
#1
```